# IBM Integration bus mqsicreatebar with references

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I'm bit confused with using mqsicreatebar in my environment. I have, for example, following file structure:

```
root
|--Libraries
|  \--Library1
\--Apps
   \--App1
      \--.project
```

And App1 is **referencing** Library1.

I want to run mqsicreatebar such that it will contain App1 with included Library1. I try to run next command in root/Apps folder:

```
mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b newbarfile.bar -cleanBuild -deployAsSource -a App1 -trace
```

I get error "Referenced project Library1 is not found on file system". What should I do to create BAR with this file structure?

Comment: What directory in that structure are you running this from? From a folder that is the parent of both (contains both) "Libraries" and "Apps"?

Comment: @Dex, No. I run it from Apps folder, as I've already mentioned in the question. Updated question a bit in order to make it a little clearer. BTW, if there is possibility to run command from "root" folder, it would be great solution, too.

Comment: Added own solution. Not perfect maybe, but solved my issue. If somebody has better option post it please, too.

Comment: Did you have an eclipse workspace (Integration Toolkit workspace) in the folder you ran it in that referenced the "external" library (external to the folder path you ran it in, at least)? That "data" parameter tells the create bar command where to find the workspace files that tells it where the project files and other files it needs are. If you don't have a workspace there already, it will create one on the fly for you, but only for the current directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: I don't know how many subdirectories it looks down (at least one), so running it in the root folder *may* allow it to find both the libraries in their sub-subfolders and the apps in their sub-subfolders, when it creates the workspace for you.

Comment: Alternatively, (and I understand this is not desired, but it's an option, similar to the one you already posted) you could give up on your organization put your library and app subfolders in the same root folder. So you have root->Library_1,Library_2,App_1,App_2. This is what I have set up in my Bamboo project and the build commands work (even with no workspace files before running the command).

Comment: Thank you, @Dex. I didn't have eclipse workspace, because it is about CI. I did try to run commands in root folder, but have been receiving an error about missing App1. But your alternative option is much better than mine. Although I cannot use this approach right now, because of wrong scm repo structure. Could you please make an answer of all your comments? Seems it may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if the comments would be helpful for your case or not, but they are useful information for others, so I'll put them in an answer.

It's odd that running it in your root directory would cause the command to search enough to know that there is an App1 (it would have to in order to know it was missing), but not enough to actually find App1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "data" parameter tells the mqsicreatebar command where to find an eclipse workspace (Integration Toolkit workspace) that in turn tells the mqsicreatebar command where the project files and other files it needs for the build are.

If you don't have a workspace there already, the command will create one on the fly for you, but only for the current directory and its subdirectories. I do not know how deep this goes. I know it looks at least one subdirectory down for project files (though your comments imply it does not look down two subdirectories).

Alternatively, (and I understand this is not desired, but it's an option, similar to the one you already posted) you could give up on your folder organization and put your library and app subfolders in the same root folder. So you have:

```
root
|--Library_1
|--Library_2
|--App_1
|--App_2
```

This is what I have set up in my Bamboo project and the build commands work (even with no workspace files before running the command, as long as I point the data parameter at this root directory).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found by myself is copying necessary artifacts to current directory before running mqsicreatebar and deleting them after build completion:

```
cd /root/Apps/
cp -R ../Libraries/Library1/ ./
mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b newbarfile.bar -cleanBuild -deployAsSource -a App1 -trace
rm -r Library1/
```